# Link 2 domains to 1 Laravel project via Nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, virtualhost, digital-ocean

I'm trying to link another domain to my existing project

[image]

I am using Laravel **5.1**, I know we only have one `APP_URL` in the .env.

Is there a way to do via **Nginx** level ?

**cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                           
    listen 80 default_server;                                                                                                                                                      
    server_name default;                                                                                                                                                           
    root /home/forge/bheng/public;                                                                                           
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;                                                                                                                                           

    index index.html index.htm index.php;                                                                                                                                          

    charset utf-8;                                                                                                                                                                 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

How would one go about configuring something like this?

Comment: It's worth noting that the `APP_URL` environment variable is only used by Laravel for cases where the `Host:` request header was not supplied, such from a console command or queued job using something like `route()` or `asset()` (where it wasn't initiated during an HTTP request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used something like this, a server name alias:

```
server_name www.app1 www.app2;
```

And then have DNS pointed to the same host. If you are working in your own linux box, change the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

And add the new hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 www.app1
127.0.0.1 www.app2
```

Comment: I know we can do the first one in `cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` but where would we configure the second part of your answer ? in what file in Linux ? `/etc/hosts` ??

Answer (score 1):

You specify the same webroot for both domains. In the Laravel code, you use Domain groups or `url('/')` to check which domain you are on.

Your config might look like this:

```
server {
     listen 80, 443;
     listen [::]:80, [::]:443;
     servername www.domain1.com www.domain2.com;

     root /home/kyo/laravel/public/;

     index index.php;

     location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you what you talking, I have a hard time imagine it. Add a bit more note to back up your points ?

Answer (score 1):

put the two domains as alias in the server name config

```
server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com domain2.com www.domain2.com ;
```

Comment: Just did that and restart the server that should works - right ? This should works with any project stack ? doesn't have to Laravel right ?

Comment: the domain config in the .env file is mainly used in CLI commands (php artisan). Also you can define routes by domain.